# Move Tool scales Reference Image

Tags: transforms, shortcut, selection-tools, transform-orientation, tools

[image]**Blender 3.6.2** - I can use the Move Tool on the Default Box and slide along the axis's by grabbing the arrows in a new file. However I can't do that after importing a Reference Image. After bringing in a Reference Image, I can only select the vertices, and this causes the Reference Image to Scale instead of Move.

I can use the **G+Y**, or **G+X**, or **G+Z** shortcuts. I can also use the Shortcut **N**, and manually enter the values. I can also use the **Object Gizmo** and turn on Move.

What I can't do is Move the Reference Image along an Axis after selecting it in Perspective View and pulling the directional arrows with a 3 button mouse. (by pulling the green or red or blue arrows)

** *Also worth noting that I have an emulated num pad.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover the cursor near an edge or a corner of the image you'll see a yellow hilight on the edge or corner vertex. Dragging with the mouse will then scale the image. However, if you move the mouse to the centre of the image the whole image will be hilighted with a thin yellow line and you can then drag the image around.

[image]

Comment: I can do this, but I can't use the arrow to slide along an axis :/

Comment: I don't think you can do that without using the Move gizmo from the L/H toolbar.